# Filtering Flink Table based on field of type Date

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I created a table which has one field of type Date, namely *f_date*. One part of my desired query filter table rows based on the *f_date* field. So I did the followings:

```java
mytable.filter("f_date <= '1998-10-02'")
```

and

```java
mytable.filter("f_date <= '1998/10/02'")
```

then I got the following same error in all two cases:

```java
Expression 'f_date <= 1998/10/02 failed on input check: Comparison is only supported for numeric types and comparable types of the same type, got Date and String
```

I even remove the single quatation and tried:

```java
mytable.filter("f_date <= 1998/10/02")
```

and I got the error:

```java
Expression 'f_date <= ((1998 / 10) / 2) failed on input check: Comparison is only supported for numeric types and comparable types of same type, got Date and Integer
```

At the end I create a Date object and try:

```java
mytable.filter("f_date <=" + Java.sql.Date.valueOf("1998-10-22"))
```

and I got the error:

```java
Expression 'f_date <= ((1998 - 10) - 2) failed on input check: Comparison is only supported for numeric types and comparable types of the same type, got Date and Integer
```

In the above cases, Flink recognized the date as String or Integer. How can I give the date in proper format!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should convert *String* to *Date* using the `toDate` method.

```
filter("f_date <= '1998-10-02'.toDate")
```